# Order By before Group By an Eloquent belongsToMany relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I want to get unique posts ordering by `project_id`, basically, if there are duplicated posts I want the one in which `project_id` is not null. **Is there any way to get this?**

This code is returning unique posts, but they are not ordered by `project_id`.

```
/**
 * Get the posts record associated with the service.
 */
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')
        ->withPivot('id', 'unity', 'coefficient', 'project_id')
        ->orderBy('project_id', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy(['post_id']);
}
```

If I remove the `groupBy`, I got duplicated posts ordered by `project_id`.

The output of `dd($service->posts()->toSql());`:

```
select * from `posts` 
inner join `post_service` on `posts`.`id` = `post_service`.`post_id` 
where `post_service`.`service_id` = ? 
group by `post_id` 
order by `project_id` desc
```

Below I show the results that I got and the result I desire:

> I removed the additional data for better reading

Result with `groupBy` and `orderBy` clauses. Unique posts but not ordered by `project_id`:

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 733,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 733,
            "id": 2575,
            "project_id": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 725,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 725,
            "id": 2576,
            "project_id": null
        }
    }
],
```

Result without `groupBy` clause. Duplicated posts ordered by `project_id`:

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 733,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 733,
            "id": 9723,
            "project_id": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 733,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 733,
            "id": 2575,
            "project_id": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 725,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 725,
            "id": 2576,
            "project_id": null
        }
    }
],
```

Result I desire. Unique posts ordered by `project_id`:

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 733,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 733,
            "id": 9723,
            "project_id": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 725,
        "pivot": {
            "service_id": 20177,
            "post_id": 725,
            "id": 2576,
            "project_id": null
        }
    }
],
```

I thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Can you post the output for $model->posts()->toSql()

Comment: @TarekAdam sure, check it.

Comment: It won't be in order if you are also grouping by  `post_id`. Did you mean you want it ordered within each group?

Comment: @thisiskelvin I updated the question with result examples, please, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving the `posts` a collection will be returned.

You can then order the results (using custom logic) in descending order by using the `->sortByDesc()` [collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortbydesc):

```
$posts = $service->posts
    ->sortByDesc(function ($post, $key) {
        return $post['pivot']['project_id'];
    })
    ->values()
    ->all();
```

Here the `posts` are sorted in decending order by the pivot's `post_id` of the `post` (not sure if this is accessed via `->` syntax or array key as I haven't tested).

To remove any duplicates (checking if `project_id` is not null) you should use `-wherePivot()`:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')
        ->withPivot('id', 'unity', 'coefficient', 'project_id')
        ->wherePivot('project_id', '=!', null)
        ->orderBy('project_id', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy(['post_id']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Your code is ordering, but it keeps duplicated posts.

ps.: The order should be by project_id.

Comment: Going to update my answer. What determines the post as unique, `project_id`?

Comment: The wherePivot condition will exclude posts with project id null, I Do not want it.

Comment: I want to get unique posts ordering by project_id, basically, if there are duplicated posts I want keep the one wich project_id is not null.

Comment: @RayannNayran Does this mean that if 2 posts both have `product_id`, both should be included in the returned results?

Comment: I Did not understand, check my result examples in the question. In the first ex. I got the post with id 733 but it pivot project_id is null. In the second I got two posts with id 733 in the correct order, but I want exclude the duplicated one with pivot project_id null. The third ex. I got two unique posts and the post with id 733 is the correct one with pivot project_id filled.

Comment: The third result example is what I want to get.